# How to make eye whites stay white at all times on an anime character?

Tags: shaders, shadows, toon-shading

I want to make an anime eye but I can't find any resources on how to make a shader/texture that retains its color no matter the lighting. Any tips?

[image: Eye whites not staying white]

Comment: Use an emission shader at 1,1,1 white, 1.0 strength, and use standard view transform or "none" display device.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, I didn't think of using an emission shader. Question though, the standard view transform, or setting the display device to "none" changes the settings for the whole scene, right?

Comment: yes they will, but otherwise you don't necessarily get the colors out that you put in.  If you want control of colors to this level, you should be doing that with color management anyways.  But if you'd rather, you might get Filmic to give you "none-more-white" by setting the emission to 11.